# Filtering the View Based on User Custom Permission

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 Models, one for a list of Courses and the other with the list of Enrollments for each User.

The Enrollment Table is currently structured to have only 1 record per student. There is a ManytoManyField in the Enrollment Table that allows me to add multiple courses for each Student.

I want to ensure that when the Student Logs in they only see Courses they have enrolled for. I can't figure out as to what query in the view is most appropriate to achieve this.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Course(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description     = models.TextField()
    created_dt      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Enrollment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ManyToManyField(Course)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.student}'s Enrollments"
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Course,Step,Enrollment
from django.http import Http404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def course_list(request):
    #courses = Course.objects.all()

    courses = Course.objects.filter(id in Enrollment.objects.filter(student=request.user))

    return render(request,"courses/course_list.html",{'courses':courses})
```

Comment: I'm not sure the modeling of `Enrollment` makes much sense here, since basically you here create an extra table. It would make more sense to see `Enrollment` itself as a *many-to-many* relation between the `Course` and the `User`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the modeling of `Enrollment` makes much sense here, since basically you here create an extra table. It would make more sense to see `Enrollment` itself as a *many-to-many* relation between the `Course` and the `User`, like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    enrollment = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model())

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

If you later want to specify some extra properties per (course, user) tuple, you can specify the [**`through`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through).

We can then obtain the list of courses with:

```
@login_required
def course_list(request):
    courses = Course.objects.filter(enrollment=request.user)
    return render(request,"courses/course_list.html", {'courses':courses})
```

If you keep using the original modeling, we can filter with:

```
@login_required
def course_list(request):
    courses = Course.objects.filter(enrollment__student=request.user)
    return render(request,"courses/course_list.html", {'courses':courses})
```

but this modeling is making things a bit "over complex".

> **Note**: if you refer to the user model, it is advisable to use the [**`get_user_model`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) function instead of `User` directly, since if you later implement a customer user model, then you will have a hard time changing everything.